# setup cart price rule from admin that only applies - if 2 out 3 specific sku are present in the cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

i need to create a cart price rule from admin in such way that if 2 out of 3 specific products need to present in the cart in order to get the discount.

For example these are the three sku's - PROD1, PROD2, PROD3. In order to apply the coupon, any of 2 mentioned SKU's need to be present in the cart.

How can i achive this.

Comment: Can you add more details about the rule ? If the 3 products are in the cart, do you still apply it ? Or is it only when axactly 2 of them are present ? Does the quantity matters ? What kind of discount di you want to apply ? For all the products in the cart, or only for those 3 products ?

Comment: Hi @Cladiuss, am applying "fixed amount discount for whole cart",  to apply that cart rule i need at least 2 out of 3 specific products.  If three products also there we can apply. it won't make any difference. we are not considering any quantity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom module, you will need to add more complex conditions.

In you case, there are 3 cases which can trigger the cart rule :

- If at least **PROD1** and **PROD2** are present
- If at least **PROD1** and **PROD3** are present
- If at least **PROD2** and **PROD3** are present

You can create 3 groups of subconditions which match this 3 cases previously mentionned.

Here would be the result :

[image: Complex Cart Price Rule]

The first group needs to be set as "Any", because if any of the following sub-conditions matches, it should trigger the rule.

Then you add the 3 groups of sub-condition.

Each of them will require at least 2 of the desired products to be present.